# how to handle inline c# code to show div tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to show div tag based on TempData["flag"], which comes from controller.

**Code 1:**

```
<div class="error_text">
    <div id="loginError" style="visibility:" +@TempData["flag"] class="errortext">
        incorrect data
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code 2:**

I tried with if condition as below. Its working, but I would like to go with the above code.

```
@if ((bool)TempData["flag"])
{
    <div class="error_text">
        <div id="loginError" class="errortext">
            incorrect data
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

How can TempData be handled in the div tag (code 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate the razor code straight into the html attribute.

```
<div class="error_text">
    <div id="loginError" style="visibility:@(((bool)TempData["flag"]) ? "visible" : "hidden")" class="errortext">
        incorrect data
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** I just noticed based on your second code section that the `flag` is just a bool value in your program, so I updated the code sample above to account for this.